# Error in class ChannelJava Sound while playing .ogg file formats using Paulscode

Tags: java, audio

I am having trouble with the Paulscode library and the Ogg plugins it uses.

For reference, I am using the newest versions of Paulscode and its plugins.

I am receving an error message

```
Error in class 'ChannelJava Sound'
    Unable to create clip in method 'attachBuffer'
    ERROR MESSAGE:
        Line unsupported: interface Clip supporting format PCM_SIGNED 8000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    STACK TRACE:
        java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.PortMixer.getLine(PortMixer.java:131)
        paulscode.sound.libraries.ChannelJavaSound.attachBuffer(ChannelJavaSound.java:249)
        paulscode.sound.libraries.SourceJavaSound.play(SourceJavaSound.java:311)
        paulscode.sound.Library.play(Library.java:706)
        paulscode.sound.Library.play(Library.java:675)
        paulscode.sound.SoundSystem.CommandPlay(SoundSystem.java:2076)
        paulscode.sound.SoundSystem.CommandQueue(SoundSystem.java:2599)
        paulscode.sound.CommandThread.run(CommandThread.java:121)
```

when trying to play the sound.
My code is

```
    private static boolean play = true;

    private static final String SEP = File.separator;

    String song;

    SoundSystem mySoundSystem;
    public Music(String songName) {
        if(!play) return;
        this.song = songName + ".ogg";
        try
        {
            SoundSystemConfig.addLibrary( LibraryJavaSound.class );
            SoundSystemConfig.setCodec( "ogg", CodecJOrbis.class );
        }
        catch( SoundSystemException e )
        {
            System.err.println("error linking with the plug-ins" );
        }
        mySoundSystem = new SoundSystem();

    }



    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(!play) return;
        if(mySoundSystem == null) error("mySoundSystem is null");
        if(song == null || song.equals("")) error("song is either null or empty!");
        mySoundSystem.quickPlay( false, song, true, 0, 0, 0, SoundSystemConfig.ATTENUATION_NONE, 0 );

    }
```

Being called by

```
Thread mus = new Thread(new Music("example"));
mus.start();
```

Naturally, this class implements java.lang.Runnable...

Things I have also tried:

- Changing the audio bitrate
- Trying other audio files

Comment: If you are interested in trying a work-around, I recommend TinySound on github. I believe it has .ogg support, and it is easy to use.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner I would like to stick with this library for now as I am considering moving this project to LWJGL and would like to use Paulscode.

Comment: Just looked more closely at the error message. You might be more successful with a more commonly used .wav format, e.g., same specs but with 44100 samples per second. At some point (IDK if within Paulscode or if the computer running the code) this older .wav format is not supported. Audacity can be used to convert the .wav if you can't get another version supplied to you with a supported .wav format. And it can be used to recompress it with ogg.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner I would rather not use wav files since they are tremendously large.  I am already using Audacity to convert mp3 to ogg, though it isn't working.